# OrderBy in documentdb linq query in IDocumentQuery

Tags: c#, sql, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I try to use `OrderBy` in `IDocumentQuery` query under `documentdb` in c#.
I try to retrieve list of courses order by distance from my place so:

```
var userQuery = _client
    .CreateDocumentQuery<Course>(_uriCourseCollection, options)
    .Where(x => x.CourseName.ToLower().Contains(text))
    .OrderBy(x =>x.GeoLocation.Location.Distance(myPoint))
    .AsDocumentQuery();
```

I received the following error message :

> "Unsupported ORDER BY clause. ORDER BY item expression could not be
>   mapped to a document path"

Someone may have solution ? , or a workaround to solved the query in efficient way ?

Comment: Have you referenced this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies)? `Azure Cosmos DB returns an error when a query uses Order By but does not have a range index against the queried path with the maximum precision.`  `Order By queries by default also require maximum index precision (-1). DataType can be String or Number`

Answer (score 0):

> "Unsupported ORDER BY clause. ORDER BY item expression could not be mapped to a document path"

According to the Azure official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies), ordering results by the ST_DISTANCE spatial function is currently not supported. I also find this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599050-azure-cosmos-db-documentdb-api/suggestions/11003184-support-order-by-on-the-st-distance-spatial-functi), you could vote it.

> Order By queries by default also require maximum index precision (-1). DataType can be **String** or **Number**